# WSO2IS 5.1.0 - Error when trying to add Federated Authenticator

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Within WSO2 Identity Server ->

Click Path:

**Service Provider**, click on *Edit*, then click on **Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration**, click on **Advanced Configuration**, and *Add Authentication Step*.  I already have Step 1 defined for Local Authenticators "basic".  For Step 2, I try to add a **Federated Authenticator** and then click **Update**.  The frame goes blank, no error, no confirmation message.

Looked at the console.log and the following error occurred.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
JSPException while including path '/application/configure-authentication-flow-finish.jsp'.  
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /application/configure-authentication-flow-finish.jsp at line 45

42:     <%
43:         String spName = request.getParameter("spName");
44:         ApplicationBean appBean = ApplicationMgtUIUtil.getApplicationBeanFromSession(session, spName);
45:         appBean.updateOutBoundAuthenticationConfig(request);
46:     %>
47: 
48:     <script>


Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:98)
... 86 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
at org.apache.jsp.application.configure_002dauthentication_002dflow_002dfinish_jsp._jspService(configure_002dauthentication_002dflow_002dfinish_jsp.java:189)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ui.ApplicationBean.updateOutBoundAuthenticationConfig(ApplicationBean.java:931)
at org.apache.jsp.application.configure_002dauthentication_002dflow_002dfinish_jsp._jspService(configure_002dauthentication_002dflow_002dfinish_jsp.java:153)
... 111 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-11 20:29:48,125] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport} -  IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/application/configure-authentication-flow-finish.jsp'. ServletException while including page. 
java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/application/configure-authentication-flow-finish.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:91)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-11 20:29:48,125] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport} -  Error during rendering 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/application/configure-authentication-flow-finish.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:84)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/application/configure-authentication-flow-finish.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:91)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
... 79 more
```

Comment: which version of IS are you using?

Comment: We are using IS 5.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I installed WSO2 IS 5.2.0 on a different server and was able to do what I couldn't do above in version 5.1.0.